# Übersetzung von "one of the very best"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Wie würde man den folgenden Satz ins Deutsche übersetzen?

> Heidelberg is one of the very best cities in Germany.

Ohne das Wort "very" würde ich sagen:

> "Heidelberg ist eine der besten Städte in Deutschland"

oder

> "Heidelberg ist eine der besten Städte Deutschlands".

Aber was macht man hier?

Comment: Heidelberg? Im Ernst? ;)

Comment: @userunknown Es gibt wirklich Schlimmeres. Es ist doch ein Glück, daß v.a. in den USA Heidelberg das Bild von Deutschland prägt, und nicht etwa Herne oder ähnliche Konglomerate menschlicher Behausungen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Man könnte es mit

> Heidelberg ist eine der allerbesten Städte Deutschlands.

übersetzen. Das ist allerdings eher umgangssprachlich und würde sich auf keinen Fall für eine Werbebroschüre oder Ähnliches eignen. Da sich der Superlativ `beste` nun mal nicht steigern lässt, kann man der Aussage auf andere Weise Nachdruck verleihen:

> Heidelberg ist wirklich eine der besten Städte Deutschlands.

Hier verstärkt `wirklich` allerdings den gesamten Satz und nicht nur das Adjektiv "gut". Eine etwas freiere Übersetzung könnte so lauten:

> Unter den besten Städten Deutschlands nimmt Heidelberg eine Spitzenposition ein.

oder

> Heidelberg gehört zu den Besten der Besten unter Deutschlands Städten.

Der Kommentar von chirlu hat mich darauf gebracht, dass eine weitere Möglichkeit in der Verwendung eines stärkeren Adjektives als `gut` besteht. Hier bietet sich `großartig` an:

> Heidelberg ist eine der großartigsten Städte Deutschlands.

Comment: +1 für Variante 1; Ob Variante 2-4: Du bist Heidelberger? ;)

Comment: @alk Hehe, nein. :)

Comment: Kann man überhaupt eine Stadt als _gut_ bezeichnen? _Schön_, _geschichtsträchtig_, _interessant_ etc. OK, aber einfach _gut_?

Comment: @chirlu Stilistisch nicht *gut*, da stimme ich voll zu. Aber mehr gibt die Vorlage nicht her. Höchstens noch *toll* oder *großartig*.

Comment: Mir gefällt das Wort "allerbesten" sehr :)

Comment: Sagen wir es gibt schlimmeres als Heidelberg. Baden Baden etwa. Was Werbebroschüren betrifft: Dort trifft man ja wohl die schlimmsten und schlechtesten Sprachkonstrukte überhaupt an - im Namen der Kreativität wird jeder Blödsinn verbrochen und gefeiert. In Werbebroschüren geht alles.

Comment: Abhängig vom Kontext wären auch folgende Alternativen vorstellbar "die lebenswerteste", "die tighteste"... oder man lässt es einfach offen und sagt "Heidelberg ist die ste Satdt Deutschlands"

Comment: ps.: Satz Nummer 3 (Spitzenposition) ist furchtbar. Journalisten, Studenten und Abiturienten schreiben manchmal so, wenn sie Angst haben zu "simpel" zu klingen